# How should I use control.invoke correctly to exclude a CS0120?

Tags: python, c#, winforms

I wrote simple application where C# (winforms) call Python ML script (so I cannot use IronPython etc.)
All worked fine and I used "invoke" correctly (I had only one process and not used class):

```
public static void appendTextData(string text)
{
    if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        richTextBox1.Invoke(new AppendTextDelegate(appendTextData), new object[] { text });
    }
        else
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(text);
    }
}
```

But when I move process creating in class (InnerPerson)  then I get error on richTextBox1:
"CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property":

```
public static void appendTextData(string text)
{
    ERROR ->    if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired) 
    {
    ERROR ->       richTextBox1.Invoke(new AppendTextDelegate(appendTextData), new object[] { text });
    }
        else
    {
    ERROR ->        richTextBox1.AppendText(text);
    }
}
```

[image]

For temporary solution I simple moved richBox declaration from Designer to Aplication and all works fine again. But am I right? Is it possible work with richBox defined in Designer?

This is my working code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        delegate void                   AppendTextDelegate(string text);
        public static string            err = "";
        public static InnerPerson[]     innerPerson = new InnerPerson[16];
        public static System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox1;
  
        public Form1()
        {
            richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 12);
            richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
            richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 350);
            Controls.Add(richTextBox1);

            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Start16();
        }
        void Start16()
        {
            innerPerson[1] = new InnerPerson();
            innerPerson[2] = new InnerPerson(); 
            innerPerson[1].Init("Uncle_Bob", 1);
            innerPerson[2].Init("Aunt_Julia", 2);

        }
        public static void OnDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
               appendTextData(e.Data + "\n");
            }
        }
        public static void appendTextData(string text)
        {
            
            if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                richTextBox1.Invoke(new AppendTextDelegate(appendTextData), new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(text);
            }
        }

        void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            string txt = textBox1.Text;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += "Me: " + txt + "";
                richTextBox1.Text += innerPerson[1].Dialog(txt, 1) + "";
                richTextBox1.Text += innerPerson[2].Dialog(txt, 2) + "";

                richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }

    }

    public class InnerPerson
    {
         public string Name = "";
 
        // Constructor
        public InnerPerson()
        {
             Name = "NoName";
        }

        public void SetName(string n) { Name = n; }
        public StreamWriter sw = null;


        public bool Init(string n, int i)
        {
            bool successRunPythonFlag = false;
            SetName(n);
            string executable = @"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Python.exe";
            string script = @"..\BOTS\chatbot.py " + i; 
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executable, script);
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            Process p = new Process();

            try
            {
                p.StartInfo = startInfo;
                p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(Form1.OnDataReceived);
               // p.ErrorDataReceived  += new DataReceivedEventHandler(Form1.OnErrorReceived);
                p.Start();
                p.BeginOutputReadLine();
                p.BeginErrorReadLine();
                sw = p.StandardInput;
                successRunPythonFlag = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                successRunPythonFlag = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                p.Close();
            }

            return successRunPythonFlag;
        }

        public string Dialog(string d, int i)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(Name + " " + d);
            return "";
        }

    }
```

So my problem is why I get errors on richbox when I define it in Constructor\Designer.

Comment: Which line does the compiler report this error?

Comment: Sorry, I'm edited post. Now You can see lines with error.

Comment: You should use `Form1.richTextBox1`.

Comment: I used it a week ago... Still no success. See picture attached. I removed "Form1." because IDE said: Name may be simplifiedЭ

Comment: It's another error now, you can search it on this site.

Comment: So You advice not simplify name and search other error? I will try change theme then...

Comment: Remove all static stuff, you need instance objects here. Use the Form as marshaler, as suggested. Set the Process' [SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject) to `this`, so you don't need to Invoke anything (you should `BeginInvoke()` anyway) and you also can check whether the Form is null or disposed before you try to access any of its members (even though the closing Form should dispose the Process).

Comment: @Jimi:  p.SynchronizingObject = Form1.richTextBox1;
          "Unavailable due to its security level".   The same problem.

Comment: ***Remove all static stuff*** + *Set the Process' SynchronizingObject to `this`*: which means `p.SynchronizingObject = this;` if the Process is created in the Form class, otherwise pass the Form instance to the class that handles the Process. E.g., add a constructor to the class as: `public InnerPerson(Form synchObj)`, then `p.SynchronizingObject = synchObj;`. So you then may have `innerPerson[1] = new InnerPerson(this);`

Comment: Is it good "pass the Form instance to the class that handles the Process" if I have a lot instances of process? May be enough pass only reachBox?

Comment: What would *enough* mean? The intended marshaller is the Form. In the procedure that sets properties of a child Control, you need to check whether that Control is null or disposed before you do anything with it. Now you can do it, since the `OutputDataReceived` event is raised in the UI Thread.

Comment: Thanks Jimi. All works now. (I'm newbie, so need in details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `SynchronizationContext` to your Form

```
private static SynchronizationContext Context;
```

And initialize in the constructor:

```
Context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

This allow you run code in your gui thread easily:

```
Context.Post(state => { /* this code run in your gui thread */ }, null);
```

So, in that part you can set values in any control of the form, not only in the `RichTextBox`. You can also redirect the event to the gui thread at first and forget this problem.

I did another change in your code, creating a Message event in the `InnerPerson` class.

```
public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> Message;
```

With this `EventArgs`:

```
public class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MessageEventArgs(string message)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public string Message { get; }
}
```

Now, your `InnerPerson` has an own message/event.

Check the full class:

```
public class InnerPerson
{
    private StreamWriter _writer = null;

    public InnerPerson()
        : this("NoName")
    {
    }

    public InnerPerson(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> Message;

    public bool Execute(int index)
    {
        bool successRunPythonFlag = false;
        string executable = @"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Python.exe";
        string script = @"..\BOTS\chatbot.py " + index;
        
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executable, script)
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        };

        Process p = new Process();

        try
        {
            p.StartInfo = startInfo;
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.OutputDataReceived += this.OnDataReceived;
            // p.ErrorDataReceived  += new DataReceivedEventHandler(Form1.OnErrorReceived);
            p.Start();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            p.BeginErrorReadLine();
            _writer = p.StandardInput;
            successRunPythonFlag = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            successRunPythonFlag = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            p.Close();
        }

        return successRunPythonFlag;
    }

    protected virtual void OnDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data) && this.Message != null)
        {
            var e2 = new MessageEventArgs(e.Data + "\n");
            this.Message(this, e2);
        }
    }

    public string Dialog(string d, int i)
    {
        this._writer.WriteLine(this.Name + " " + d);
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And now, in the form, you need to do some adjustments:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static SynchronizationContext Context;

    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    public static string err = "";
    public static InnerPerson[] innerPerson = new InnerPerson[16];

    void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Start16();
    }

    void Start16()
    {
        string[] names = new[] { "Uncle_Bob", "Aunt_Julia" };

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            var person = innerPerson[i] = new InnerPerson(names[i]);

            person.Message += (sender, e) =>                 
                Context.Post(state => this.OnPerson_Message(sender, e), null);

            person.Execute(i + 1);
        }
    }

    private void OnPerson_Message(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Message);
    }

    void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string txt = textBox1.Text;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "Me: " + txt + "";
            richTextBox1.Text += innerPerson[1].Dialog(txt, 1) + "";
            richTextBox1.Text += innerPerson[2].Dialog(txt, 2) + "";

            richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, we use the `Message` event of `InnerPerson` to get the messages and `Context` to redirect these messages to GUI thread: you don't need to do nothing about `BeginInvoke` in `OnPerson_Message`, just work with your controls.